# Create database unique Surrogate Keys without using GUID’s

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, normalization, best-practices

What is the best way to get database unique surrogate keys in Microsoft SQL Server when using something like “auto increment” as opposed to GUID's. The purpose is to increase performance over using GUID's. I have heard the term "Key Table" but cant find any information relating to these.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks. Yes I meant Database unique- I have updated the question.

Comment: On 2012+ you could use a sequence object if I understand you correctly. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Sequence. A sequence is a database-wide generator of unique integers that can provide unique surrogate keys.